# Windows - remove cached works or school accounts

Tags: windows, azure-active-directory

Is there a command, powershell cmdlet, api, sdk, gpo or registry entry that I can use to get rid of all cached accounts under Settings -> Access work or school?

They are not stored in credential manager and cannot be access by cmdkey.

[Windows 10 -> Settings -> Access work or school](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGkn1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could manually to remove the account in Settings -> Other people.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am aware of how to manually remove them. I specifically asked for a programmatic way to remove the accounts.

Comment: As I know, there is no PowerShell cmd to make this.